# Testing a C++ Linked Implementation Error

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to test out the code my professor gave us. We have to change the implementation of the code but that is not what I am stuck on. I am stuck on making a working test code. He gave me the test code to run but when I try to run it I keep getting errors which shouldn't be the case. Could anyone tell me what the problem is in my test code so I can start changing and adding different functions into my code? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
// ListNode.h
#ifndef _LISTNODE_H
#define _LISTNODE_H

#include <cstdlib>

typedef int ItemType;

class ListNode {
    friend class LList;

public:
    ListNode(ItemType item, ListNode* link = NULL);

private:
    ItemType item_;
    ListNode *link_;
};

inline ListNode::ListNode(ItemType item, ListNode *link)
{
    item_ = item;
    link_ = link;
}

#endif // _LISTNODE_H
```

---

```
// LList.h
#ifndef _LLIST_H
#define _LLIST_H

#include "ListNode.h"

class LList {

public:
    LList();
    LList(const LList& source);
    ~LList();

    LList& operator=(const LList& source);
    int size() { return size_; }
    void append(ItemType x);
    void insert(size_t i, ItemType x);
    ItemType pop(int i = -1);
    ItemType& operator[](size_t position);

private:
    // methods
    void copy(const LList &source);
    void dealloc();
    ListNode* _find(size_t position);
    ItemType _delete(size_t position);

    // data elements
    ListNode *head_;
    int size_;
};

#endif // _LLIST_H
```

---

```
// LList.cpp
#include "LList.h"

LList::LList()
{
    head_ = NULL;
    size_ = 0;
}

ListNode* LList::_find(size_t position)
{
    ListNode *node = head_;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i<position; i++) {
        node = node->link_;
    }
    return node;
}

ItemType LList::_delete(size_t position)
{
    ListNode *node, *dnode;
    ItemType item;

    if (position == 0) {
        dnode = head_;
        head_ = head_->link_;
        item = dnode->item_;
        delete dnode;
    }
    else {
        node = _find(position - 1);
        if (node != NULL) {
            dnode = node->link_;
            node->link_ = dnode->link_;
            item = dnode->item_;
            delete dnode;
        }
    }
    size_ -= 1;
    return item;
}

void LList::append(ItemType x)
{
    ListNode *node, *newNode = new ListNode(x);

    if (head_ != NULL) {
        node = _find(size_ - 1);
        node->link_ = newNode;
    }
    else {
        head_ = newNode;
    }
    size_ += 1;
}

void LList::insert(size_t i, ItemType x)
{
    ListNode *node;

    if (i == 0) {
        head_ = new ListNode(x, head_);
    }
    else {
        node = _find(i - 1);
        node->link_ = new ListNode(x, node->link_);
    }
    size_ += 1;
}

ItemType LList::pop(int i)
{
    if (i == -1) {
        i = size_ - 1;
    }
    return _delete(i);
}

ItemType& LList::operator[](size_t position)
{
    ListNode *node;

    node = _find(position);
    return node->item_;
}

LList::LList(const LList& source)
{
    copy(source);
}

void LList::copy(const LList &source)
{
    ListNode *snode, *node;

    snode = source.head_;
    if (snode) {
        node = head_ = new ListNode(snode->item_);
        snode = snode->link_;

    while (snode) {
        node->link_ = new ListNode(snode->item_);
        node = node->link_;
        snode = snode->link_;
    }
    size_ = source.size_;
}

LList& LList::operator=(const LList& source)
{
    if (this != &source) {
        dealloc();
        copy(source);
    }
    return *this;
}

LList::~LList()
{
    dealloc();
}

void LList::dealloc()
{
    ListNode *node, *dnode;

    node = head_;
    while (node) {
        dnode = node;
        node = node->link_;
        delete dnode;
    }
}
```

---

```
#include "LList.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LList b, c;
    int x;

    b.append(1);
    b.append(2);
    b.append(3);
    c.append(4);
    c.append(5);
    c = b;
    x = b.pop();

    cout << c;
}
```

Could anyone help me write a working test code, this the last thing I will need to start adding my different functions.

I keep getting this error:

```
Error   1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'LList' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    c:\users\koopt_000\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\lab10\lab10\testlist.cpp   18  1   Lab10
```

Any help?

Comment: You haven't defined an inserter for the `LList` class.

Comment: And fyi, `LList::copy` appears to be missing its closing `}` somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code:

`cout << c;`

is the problem.  You cannot print your linked list that way (Edit: Unless you have an overload for the operator `<<` which does not appear in your code).

For printing the elements, you can iterate through the list starting from the first node to the last. Something like that would work:

```
void LList::printList()
{ 
    ListNode *tmp = head_;

    while(tmp) {
        std::cout<<tmp->item_;
        tmp=tmp->link_;
    }      
}
```

PS: don`t forget the put the method prototype into the class definition. And of course in your main method can call to the function as follows:

```
...
c.printList();
....
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: *"You cannot print the linked list that way"* You can if you define the `ostream operator<<` for the `LList` class

Comment: I said " the linked list" which means the linked list that is defined here. I did not say "a linked list" ;) Edit: Changed "the" to "your", which might be better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to output your `LList`, but it's not quite that straight forward. You need to overload the output operator:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const LList& list) {
    // Write code here to iterate through the list
    // and output each item...

    // Return the stream so we can chain outputs..
    return stream;
}
```